# how to change the shape color looping over an interval table infinitely in js?

Tags: javascript, date, settimeout

I have a table that looks like

```
duration/ms color
10 red
16 yellow
10 red
20 blue
...
```

I want my shape to display the color following the duration-color table, and restart from the beginning when it reaches the end.

How may I ask the js to wait the 10ms? I've tried

1.write a loop going through the table, and use Date.now() to control the transition

```
while (true) {
    startingTime = Date.now()
    duration = table[index]
    while (Date.now() < startingTime + duration) {
        continue
    }
    //changeColor
    //updateIndex
}
```

Too consuming. Blowed my browser.

2.setTimeout

```
var index = 1
var updateColor = function() {
    //updateshapecolor(color_table[index])
    //updateinex
    setTimeout(updateColor, duration_table[index])

}
updateColor()
```

Works well for small table but got really slow in large table, and eventually blowed the stack.

What would be a better practice? Can someone kindly suggest?

Comment: What is your shape?  Can you show the html for that please

Answer (score 2):

This kind of simple animation can likely be done in css with a lot less strain on the browser.  Here's an example that uses your data to construct a stylesheet with the right animation settings to change the "color".  You might need to change the "background-color" or something else instead.

```js
//Your data
var data = [
  {color: "red", ms: 10},
  {color: "yellow", ms: 16},
  {color: "red", ms: 10},
  {color: "blue", ms: 20}
];

// calculate the total time
var totalms = data.reduce((acc,obj) => acc + obj.ms, 0);

var runningtot = 0;

// build the keyframes
var style = data.reduce((str,obj) => {
  var pct = runningtot / totalms * 100;
  runningtot += obj.ms;
  str += pct + "% { color: " + obj.color + "; }";
  return str;
}, "");

var totallength = totalms / 1000 + "s";

// create a class called pulser
style = ".pulser {animation: pulse " + totallength + " infinite;} @keyframes pulse { " + style + " }";

// the stylesheet contents
console.log(style);

// append it to the document
var ss = document.createElement('style');
ss.innerHTML = style;
document.body.appendChild(ss);
```

```html
<div class='pulser'>Example Text</div>
```

Comment: The style can be static if CSS variables are allowed :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The reason I didn't use pure css is because this is in a React APP and the table is dynamically pulled ( long polling) from a server. Not sure how CSS fits in the picture

Comment: based on your reply, I found a package that might serve the same purpose in React https://github.com/zeit/react-keyframes

Answer (score 1):

you may use `requestAnimationFrame`
it doesn't consume your performance like infinit loop because it calls the callback only when 1/60 of second passed

```
let index = 0;
let lastTime = 0; /* unix timestamp */

/* draw callback */
/* [curTime] - current time in unix timestamp */
let onDraw = function(curTime) {

    if (curTime > lastTime + table[index])
    {
        /* update state of index */
        index = (index + 1) % table.length;

        /* update state of last time */
        lastTime = curTime;

        /* change color here */
    }

    /* wait for next update */
    requestAnimationFrame(onDraw);
}

/* start the animation */
requestAnimationFrame(onDraw);
```

Comment: this solves the precision issue, but not the being slow issue.  The originally interval granularity (~20ms), wihtout the time checker, already made the React App slow in animations....